# Android Development: How do I predict expected battery life based on current battery level?

Tags: android, batterylevel

I have a requirement of predicting the battery duration from within my android app. I have the cpu data, memory information and current battery level. I have also plotted graphs of these values over the past few minutes using the AndroidPlot library. Using these data (or anything else), what is the best way of predicting the time before the battery runs out on the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always try to predict something but the question would be how accurate the prediction is?

Based on the Data (cpu, memory and battery level) you can create a database and keep track of every application battery consumption. And, using of those information you can always generate a prediction. You can use [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) to get list of running process.

Second, Read this interesting [Article](http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/efficient-network-access.html) thoroughly and use [WiFiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) to collect wifi state, wireless radios are a big battery drainer.For more accuracy you can even check Bluetooth radio status. Make sure to combine all these with [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html).

Third, use power manager to check display staus.

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
 boolean isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
```

Combine all these together to make a better prediction.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I will get back here once I start working on it.